# jQuery selector vs. filter unexpected result

Tags: javascript, jquery

`html` is a piece of HTML containing inline Javascript resulting from an AJAX request. The following code:

```
$(html).filter('script')
```

returns a jQuery object for each script tag, whereas:

```
$('script', $(html))
```

returns an empty array. How is this possible? I'm using Chromium 10.0.

Comment: `$('script', $(html))` do check if $(html) node is not your desired <script> tag. For this to work 'script' should be child of $(html) jquery object. That is my understanding.

Comment: This has something to do with DOM scope, but for some reason it doesn't work for `script` tags *at all* when I test it.

Comment: @Ajaxe, you are right, this turns out to be a scoping issue.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that $('script', $(html)) is turned into

```
$(html).find('script')
```

not

```
$(htmls).filter('script');
```

I believe that script tags of a certain type are removed from strings under the guise of keeping IE happy. A year ago, I delved into the jQuery source and found where it did that, but I can't remember why it did that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok got something here, I wonder if answer is still relevant or not anyways here it goes.
Create a new JS file say it as "scriptTagTest.js" add the following js code

```
var html = '<div>I am DIV</div><script type="text/javascript">alert("I am inline");</script>';  
$(document).ready(function(e){  
  $('#inStr').text(html);  
});  

$('#test1').live('click', function(e){  
    var $html = $(html);  
  var o = $html.filter('script');  
  check(o);  
});  

$('#test2').live('click', function(e){  
    var $html = $(html);  
  var o = $('script', $html);  
  check(o);  
});  

function check($o, $html){  
  alert('obj len:'+ $o.length);  
    var $testArea = $('#testArea');  
  if($o.length > 0){  
    $testArea.append($o);  
  }  
  else{  
    $testArea.text('No script obj');  
  }  
}
```

and then the html file as

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--[if IE]>
      <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="scriptTagTest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="hello">Hello World</p>
  <div id="inStr">test</div>
  <button id="test1">Test $(html).filter('script')</button>
  <button id="test2">Test $('script', $(html))</button>
  <div id="testArea">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
</html>
```

click "Test1" and "Test2" to see the results. Interestingly, the browser didn't parse the variable `html` with the `<script>` tag properly which I haven't come across earlier, thats why another JS file.

`find()` is used to look into the child elements while `filter()` finds in flat list of objects as well. If you incoming html is is in the form of the `html` variable then that might explain something.
Tested this in chrome 8 (desktop), FF, IE latest versions. Hope this helps. Best would be to drill down using Firebug!!